# как осуществить вставку полей из Arraylist в строку POST запроса?

Tags: android, post, soap, arraylist

есть запрос к серверу, формирую строку и вставляю определенный данные,  пробую вставить данные из списка, но, кажется, это костыль, как еще можно осуществить вставку данных?

```
public void formationShoppingList(ArrayList<Model> list) {
        String temp="";
        String str;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            str =
                    "<ProductName" + i + ">" + list.get(i).getName_tovar() + "</ProductName" + i + ">\n" +
                            "<ProductBrand" + i + ">" + list.get(i).getMark_tovar() + "</ProductBrand" + i + ">\n" +
                            "<ProductPrice" + i + ">" + list.get(i).getCost_tovar() + "</ProductPrice" + i + ">\n";
            temp+=str;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через Map.

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("name1", "value1");
params.put("name2", "value2");
```

Далее params пишете в OutputStream

```
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getPostDataString(params));// функция которая делает строку, ниже ее код
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
```

Вот функция подготавливающая строку.

```
private String getPostDataString(Map<String,String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

По материалам [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post/13486223#13486223). Там более подробно.

Comment: я читал тот вопрос, но опять же получается что 
params.put("name1", "value1");
params.put("name2", "value2");
 мы должны прописывать руками, это не проблема, но у меня может быть 10 name, а может и 1. вот как этот момент отловить

Comment: @Сергей погоди, у тебя же в любом случае где-то должны быть исходно заданны твои параметры, пусть хоть и 10 штук или 1 штук. В каком они у тебя виде изначально? Или откуда ты их получаешь и в каком виде?

Comment: у меня есть alert dialog через который я ввожу данные, потом они у меня сохраняются в arraylist, и да количество элементов из list я могу взять, но оно каждый раз разное..или я чего -то не понимаю..

Comment: @Сергей понял, у тебя юзер сам создает параметры, которые ты потом отправишь на сервер. Кол-во параметров может быть разным? Данные от юзеров попадают в Arraylist, т.е. он можно сказать он создается программно и его размер может быть каждый раз разный. Ты потом распариваешь свой Arraylist в строку, твое решение вроде не костыль, по чему оно тебя смущает? Таким образом можно результаты alertDialoga записать и в Map и использовать решение что я предложил. В любом случае результат будет строка, которую ты загонишь в outputStream.

Comment: просто подумал можно ли как-то красивее сделать, вроде того как описать структуру запроса 1 раз, и на вход сразу подавать ей список и она чтобы сама парсила поля.. видимо библиотеку надо посмотреть